# Как сделать редирект скрола с одной страницы на другой в react-scroll?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

есть меню на React:

```
<List sx={{display: "flex", marginLeft: "30px"}}>
                                {pages.map((page, index) => (
                                    <ListItemButton key={index}>
                                        <ListItemIcon>
                                            <LinkScroll activeClass="active" spy={true}
                                                        smooth={true}
                                                        offset={-100}
                                                        duration={500}
                                                        style={{color: "black", textDecoration: "none"}}
                                                        to={page.tags}><ListItemText id={"#" + page.tags}
                                                                                     sx={{fontFamily: "Mulish"}}>{page.title}</ListItemText></LinkScroll>
                                        </ListItemIcon>
                                    </ListItemButton>
                                ))}
                            </List>
```

На главной страницы скрол на элемент работает нормально, но мне нужно перейти по нажатии на ссылку на главную и перенаправить на тот элемент на который нажал.
Пробовал так:

```
<LinkScroll activeClass="active" spy={true}
                                                        smooth={true}
                                                        offset={-100}
                                                        duration={500}
                                                        style={{color: "black", textDecoration: "none"}}
                                                        to={"/" + page.tags}><ListItemText id={"#" + page.tags} //так не прокатывает он не переходить, пишет rget Element not found

                                                                                     sx={{fontFamily: "Mulish"}}>{page.title}</ListItemText></LinkScroll>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать.